# Can you set up a WCF Service Reference without cluttering up your app.config?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a dirt simple web service hosted in IIS that I need to reference.  If I add a 'Service Reference', my app.config gets cluttered up with tons of `<system.serviceModel>` stuff.  If I change the *Service Reference* to the old style *Web Reference*, I get the one and only configuration option I actually need in my app.config - the URL of the web service.

Is all the junk that a WCF Service Reference pollutes your app.config with required?  Or is there a way to get it to use reasonable defaults and remove all the `bindings` and `endpoints` and clutter that was never necessary in the old ASMX web service days.  As more and more services are added, this seems like the .config file is going to get unwieldy fast.

Comment: You can do it all in code if you prefer, but better to turn a blind eye to those sections of app.config and let them do their job. Try deleting some of it when your app is working and you'll find words like "junk" and "pollute" don't apply - you need that stuff.

Comment: *I* don't need all that stuff.  But, of course the web service absolutely does to do it's job, sure.  I'm looking for whether there's a way for these things to be initialized as reasonable defaults.  While obviously limited, the old ASMX web services worked this way, with nearly zero configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is all the junk that a WCF Service Reference pollutes your app.config with required?

Totally agree with you. Pure junk. I use [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate strongly typed clients to my WCF services. Then I manually include the generated `.cs` file into my project and in my web/app.config I manually include what I judge necessary and not what some crappy Add Service Reference Wizard decided to do. In most cases all I need is this on the client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint
          address="http://example.com/fooservice/foo.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="IFooServiceConbtract" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Of course for services where I use MTOM and some fancy stuff I look at the autogenerated `app.config` file by the `svcutil.exe` command and I decide what I need.

Comment: How did you wind up without the whole binding configuration?

Comment: @mattmc3, what binding configuration are you talking about? All I know is that my service uses `basicHttpBinding` (I know it coz I wrote the service :-)). And that's all I need to tell to the client => `binding="basicHttpBinding"` as shown in my example. If I had used `wsHttpBinding` I would have adapted my client. Easy peasy.

Comment: You're absolutely right!  Awesome!  I hadn't defined the basicHttpBinding endpoint on my test service, so I was getting a whole output.config file from svcutil with a custom wsHttpBinding defined.  Now I'm only left with the question of why on earth doesn't the Add Service Reference dialog just do it this way?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework version 4 addresses these problems and provides users a way to reduce the size and complexity of service configuration.  Here is the link for [Simplified Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx)

Comment: I'm on 4.0/VS2010.  Do you have to manually trim this down after you add your service reference, because when I add the references my app.config looks nothing near as simple as that.

Comment: @mattmc3 You are right even in .NET 4.0 it is still some extra information.  So I always remove what is autogenerated to basic minimum and add extra as I need it.  Here is my starting point after what VS generates:      <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/VCIndex/Calculator.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Miguel Castro's Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) screencast with DotNet Rocks TV - he shows exactly what you're looking for, and how to achieve nice, clean WCF configs (as long as you don't let Visual Studio and svcutil mess them up!).